# Creating a Reflection Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I am attempting to reflect onto the X-Z plane a rotating cube (so ultimately this is a 3D to 2D projection). However, the points with which my cube is projected onto the X-Z plane overlap, as expected due to the fact that the cube is 3D and there are points with the same X values, but different y values (2 points are projected onto the same point).

My question is, how can I project only the points on my cube that are visible to the plane I want to project onto?

```
glLoadIdentity();

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glCullFace(GL_BACK);

        glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);

        GLfloat matrix[16] = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
                              0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 
                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};

        glPushMatrix();
            glRotatef(angle, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
                DrawCube();     
            glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();

        glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
            glMultMatrixf(matrix);
            glRotatef(angle, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
                DrawCube();
            glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> reflect onto the X-Z plane a rotating cube (so ultimately this is a 3D to 2D projection).

A reflection is not a singular projection (what you call 3D to 2D). A reflection is a scaling of -1, in your desired case the scaling is `glScalef(1, -1, 1)`.